# Swift - Creating custom functions for NSExpression

Tags: ios, swift, function

I am using NSexpression to evaluate a math equation in string form, for a project I am working on as a beginner, an example string being:

```
"12 + 3 - sqrt(4) * 9"
```

This seems to work great for basic math operations, but not for the more advanced stuff that I need, such as cubed roots and factorials.

I have tried creating custom functions as an extension of NSnumber but I keep drawing blanks. Any suggestions on how to fix this, or a completely different method to evaluate an equation in string form? This is what I have tried in playground:

```
import UIKit

public extension NSNumber {

    func factorial() -> NSNumber {
        var xDouble = self as! Double
        var index = xDouble - 1
        while index > 1 {
            xDouble = xDouble * index
            index = index - 1
        }
        return xDouble as NSNumber
    }
}

let equation = "function(3, 'factorial')"
let expression = NSExpression(format: equation)
let result = expression.expressionValue(with: nil, context: nil) as! Double
```

However, this returns the following error:

```
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT.
The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.
```

Thanks very much

Comment: This tutorial might be interesting for you: https://nshipster.com/nsexpression/

Answer (score 4):

you need to use @objc

```
import UIKit

@objc
public extension NSNumber {

    func factorial() -> NSNumber {
        var xDouble = self as! Double
        var index = xDouble - 1
        while index > 1 {
            xDouble = xDouble * index
            index = index - 1
        }
        return xDouble as NSNumber
    }
}

let equation = "function(3, 'factorial')"
let expression = NSExpression(format: equation)
let result = expression.expressionValue(with: nil, context: nil) as! Double
```

https://qiita.com/on0z/items/ac7074b52bfc049dfbe3